# Use PHP to put data onto server ( new DOMdocument not working)

Tags: php, domdocument, file-handling

I've been trying to incorporate a log of usage on my website. 
I'm using the following PHP code for it..

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
$named = new DOMDocument();
echo "is";
$named->loadHTMLFile("html/trial12.htm");
echo "anybody";
$fartele = $named->getElementById("art");
echo "home?";
$value = $fartele->textContent;
echo $value;
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$file=fopen("logofusage.out","a+");
fwrite($file,$value);
fwrite($file,",");
fwrite($file,$ip);
fwrite($file,",");
$timevariable = date("l dS \of F Y h:i:s A")."\n";
fwrite($file,$timevariable);
fclose($file);
?>
```

The echo thing is for debugging. But I can seem to get the script to run on my university's webserver. If I use just some predefined value for "$value" variable, and comment out the top part, I can see that the logofusage file is being populated. But when I use the script as above, I can't get past the "Hello". So I figure the problem is on the "new DOMDocument " line. Can anyone tell me what it could be?

P.S. Just to clarify a bit more, I am using Javascript to accept an input from the user and saving it to a "div" element in the HTML file, and then accessing the text inside the "div" element.
 The server uses PHP Version 5.3.1 .  And my HTML document has a doctype HTML 4.01 Transitional

Thanks for the help. :)
Ajrocker

#### So the university server does not have the DOMDocument extension. Guess that's that

Is there any other way to pull data from the HTML file and post it onto the server without AJAX...

Comment: Did you enable error_reporting for E_ALL? Why don't you use a normal tool for debugging like XDebug?

Comment: Actually not my server to boot.. Its the university server. Its for my homepage there. Although I did check right now and display_errors is off and error_reporting is 22527.

Comment: If you use Javascript to populate the div, it won't be saved to the HTML file on the server...

Comment: But it should be accessible while the page is still active right ? That is when I am running the PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't get past

new DOMDocument();

then I guess this extension is not available.

B/c there is not much that could be wrong with your script up to this point.

Check the output of [phpinfo](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)() and/or [get_loaded_extensions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php)() to see which are available.

[Also libxml is required to get DOMDocument do its job.](http://de.php.net/manual/en/dom.requirements.php)

Comment: Yeah... the last get_loaded_extensions() revealed that the DOMDocument() actually did not exist. Thanks for that.. We do have libxml but not DOMDocument :(

Comment: Is there any other way to pull data from the HTML file and post it onto the server without AJAX..

Comment: depending on the complexity of your html file you might just use regex (as long as this is not used for sanitizing input of course). why not just get dom up and running? and if you want to post something somewhere you can use a regular post request, instead of sneaking it through with ajax.

Comment: Its the university's server.. so I can't really force them to get DOMDocument up and running.. I'm not very sure how to use a POST request .. do I use javascript, or some other language for it ? I am new to web development. and if its PHP, how do I give it the user input w/o DOMDocument ?

Comment: I fear there's no way around getting the basics straight.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your DOMDocument extension is enabled (using phpinfo() or cli).